# How to export an html table as a PDF or image?

Tags: php, html, image, pdf

I am working on creating a website which will allow users to update a table using Javascript.

What I am looking for is a way to allow the user to export the table as an image (jpg, png etc.) or a PDF once it has been modified.

If there is a similar thread or topic please let me know, I don't really know where to start here. If you can recommend background reading that would be great too.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that can really be done client side (without installing software on the clients, of course).  You will need to generate this PDF server-side.

How you do that depends on the language and platform you are using.

Comment: Thats not entirely correct. There is a JS library that generates pdf files. http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/

Comment: As far as server side language goes I can use PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple open source PDF librarys you can use;

SharPDF, PDFClown, iTextSharp  just to name a few...

Comment: Anything that can export as an image?